# Best way to store high frequency, periodic time-series data?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, architecture, storage

I have created an MVP for a nodejs project, following are some of the features that are relevant to the question I am about to ask:

1-The application has a list of IP addresses with CRUD actions.
2-The application will ping each IP address after every 5 seconds.
3- And display against each IP address it's status i.e alive or dead and the uptime if alive

I created a working MVP on nodejs with the help of the library net-ping, express, mongo and angular. Now I have a new feature request that is:

"to calculate the round trip time(latency) for each ping that is generated for each IP address and populate a bar chart or any type of chart that will display the RTT(latency) history(1 months-1 year) of every connection"

I need to store the response of each ping in the database, Assuming the best case that if each document that I will store is of size 0.5 kb, that will make 9.5MB data to be stored in each day,285MB in each month and 3.4GB in a year for a single IP address and I am going to have 100-200 IP addresses in my application.

What is the best solution (including those which are paid) that will suit the best for my requirements considering the app can scale more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed The schema design for the Time-series data after reading [this](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb) and that reduced the numbers in my calculation of size massively

previous Schema looked like this:

```
{
  timestamp: ISODate("2013-10-10T23:06:37.000Z"),
  type: "Latency",
  value: 1000000
},
{
  timestamp: ISODate("2013-10-10T23:06:38.000Z"),
  type: "Latency",
  value: 15000000
}
Size of each document: 0.22kb
number of document created in an hour= 720
size of data generated in an hour=0.22*720 = 158.4kb
size of data generated by one IP address in a day= 158 *24 = 3.7MB
```

Since every next time_Stamp is just the increment of 5 seconds from the previous one, the schema can be optimized to cut the redundant data.
The new schema looks like this :

```
{
  timestamp_hour: ISODate("2013-10-10T23:06:00.000Z"),// will contain hours
  type: “Latency”,
  values: {//will contain data for all pings in the specific hour
    0: 999999,
    …
    37: 1000000,
    38: 1500000,
    … 
    720: 2000000
  }
}
Size of each document: 0.5kb
number of document created in an hour= 1
size of data generated in an hour= 0.5kb
size of data generated by one IP address in a day= 0.5 *24 = 12kb
```

So I Am assuming the size of the data will not be an issue anymore, and I although there is a debate for what type of storage should be used in such scenarios to ensure best performance but I am going to trust mongoDB in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Time series data require special treatment from a database perspective as they introduce challenges to the traditional database management from capacity, query performance, read/write optimisation targets, etc.

I wouldn't recommend you store this data in a traditional RDBMS, or object/document database.

Best option is to use a specialised time-series database engine, like [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-platform/influxdb/), that can support downsampling (aggregation) and raw data retention rules